# How do I print a sorted Dictionary in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, printing

I am studying for my GCSE part of which requires me to print a dictionary sorted alphabetically by key and the print should include the associated value.

I have spent hours trying to find the answer to this and have looked at various posts on this forum but most are too complex for my limited knowledge.

I can print alphabeticallycsorted Keys and I can print sorted values but not alphabetically sorted keys with the values attached.

This is my simple test code

```
class1 = { 'Ethan':'9','Ian':'3','Helen':'8','Holly':'6' } # create dictionary

print(sorted(class1)) # prints sorted Keys
print(sorted(class1.values())) # Prints sorted values
```

I need to print sorted keys with values - how to do that?

```
for k,v in class1.items():
    print(k,v)  # prints out in the format I want but not alphabetically sorted
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
>>> class1 = { 'Ethan':'9','Ian':'3','Helen':'8','Holly':'6' }
>>> print(sorted(class1.items()))
[('Ethan', '9'), ('Helen', '8'), ('Holly', '6'), ('Ian', '3')]
```

```
>>> for k,v in sorted(class1.items()):
...     print(k, v)
...
Ethan 9
Helen 8
Holly 6
Ian 3
```

```
>>> for k,v in sorted(class1.items(), key=lambda p:p[1]):
...     print(k,v)
...
Ian 3
Holly 6
Helen 8
Ethan 9

>>> for k,v in sorted(class1.items(), key=lambda p:p[1], reverse=True):
...     print(k,v)
...
Ethan 9
Helen 8
Holly 6
Ian 3
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I do it so that it prints as a list down the page without the brackets etc?
for k,v in class1.items(): print(k,v) # prints out in the format I want but not alphabetically sorted.

Comment: Brilliant. I knew it would be simple but couldn't get my head around it.
Thanks Kevin much appreciated.

Comment: I tested this code. But, it seems to sort the dictionary by keys and not values.

Answer (score 0):

```
class1 = { 'Ethan':'9','Ian':'3','Helen':'8','Holly':'6' }
class1_keys = class1.keys()
class1_keys.sort()
for i in class1_keys:
        print(i,class1[i])
Ethan 9
Helen 8
Holly 6
Ian 3
```