# Python - Sorting a specific piece of a dictionary from least to greatest number

Tags: python, python-3.6

My output:
[image]

What it's supposed to look like:
[image]

My code:
[image]

My output:

```
Jersey number: 84, Rating: 7
Jersey number: 4, Rating: 5
Jersey number: 66, Rating: 9
```

Asking for:

```
Jersey number: 4, Rating: 5
Jersey number: 66, Rating: 9
Jersey number: 84, Rating: 7
```

I am not sure how to get the jersey numbers in the desired order, I've tried a variety of ways and I'm still unsure. The specific order is where it's getting me. Any ideas?
Thank you for reading!

Comment: Please include the code from your question as text that can be copied instead of linking to images - helps those that want to try and run it actually run it

Comment: Also [How do I print a sorted Dictionary in Python 3.4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609991/how-do-i-print-a-sorted-dictionary-in-python-3-4-3)

Comment: @Adrien Arbuckle Please be specific with your query and explain all the variables you have used in the code. What is rating_above and team whether it is a dictionary or an array of dict?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to sort the dict by the keys, which happens to be the first item of the item tuples, you can simply sort the dict items by the tuple order instead:

```
for jersey, rating in sorted(team.items()):
```